# NotificationListenerService works intermittently for Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have a class

```
public class NotifClass extends  NotificationListenerService{
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

@Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
String notifiTitle = getActiveNotifications()[i].getNotification().extras.getString("android.title");
}
}
```

I've put a breakpoint at

```
String notificationTitle = getActiveNotifications()[i].getNotification().extras.getString("android.title");
```

inside onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) method.

This is a callback method which is called when device receives any notification.
It works perfectly fine while running over Android Nougat.
But it hits intermittently in Android Oreo. Sometimes it hits and sometimes doesn't.

I'm not sure about the real issue and its solution but can I read activeNotifications using JobScheduler as I'm facing issue with Service?
I'm running over API 26

Comment: how you starting service?

Comment: I've put it as BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE in AndroidManifest.xml  <service
            android:name=".Services.NotifClass"
            android:label="NotifClass"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

Comment: As per [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) it should be called automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been working over this issue for quite a long. When I'm running it over Google Nexus/pixel device or emulator, this service works intermittently.
I tried running it over Honor and Samsung S9 and `NotificationListenerService` works perfectly fine in that.
So I concluded that the issue is with Google devices and not the service.

Just a note that if the device is running on low-RAM, there are great chances that `NotificationListenerService` will stop working.