# When app clear from recent apps list, background service stopped in android nougat and oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

When I clear my app from recent apps list, my app background service killed. I tried with android nougat and oreo. But it's working in Android 6.0. After searched about the issue. Lot of people navigated the answer to [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).

Any one have solution for this issue?

Comment: You need to do a foreground service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 1):

Android Nougat should not have those issues ideally. I've spend weeks on `NotificationListenerService` which runs perfectly fine in background in Nougat.
It also works great in Samsung S9 (Android Oreo) but I have some issues in Google devices and emulators.
I've raised a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629526/notificationlistenerservice-works-intermittently-for-oreo?noredirect=1#comment90223299_51629526) few weeks back.

Just to make sure, enable background services for your app through console.
Also, specify which service you are using?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void moveToStartedState() {
        Intent intent = new MyIntentBuilder(this)
            .setCommand(Command.START).build();
        if (isPreAndroidO()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Running on Android N or lower");
            startService(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Running on Android O");
            startForegroundService(intent);
        }
    }
```

**Example**

https://proandroiddev.com/deep-dive-into-android-services-4830b8c9a09

Answer (score 1):

**Simple answer:**

Use foreground services instead of background services.

**Why?**

Because of [changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) in how latest Android SDKs treat background services and [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

---

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have android nougat 7.1.2, mobile RedMi5A. At beginning my background service worked very well. But yesterday to that background service functions are killed and the services are not restarted when I clear my app from recent apps. I checked 1.Autostart, 2.Battery Consumptions, 3. Background service all are enabled. Now the problem is that background service is not restarting when i swiped app from recent app list.

Comment: Maybe you changed something in the code? Tried reinstalling your app?

Comment: I didn't changed, Because of that app in play store. That's what I totally confused. It's too strange. But it's perfectly working in Android 6.0.

Comment: Using foreground service is relevant only for specific scenarios, so I think it might not be the right solution for this problem (see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9323576/997940)